# Some [Bindable] properties in Flex work, some don't

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, bindable

***Problem solved, see below***

## Question

I'm working in Flex Builder 3 and I have two ActionScript 3 classes (`ABC` and `XYZ`) and a Flex MXML project (`main.mxml`).  I have an instance of `XYZ` as a property of `ABC`, and I want `XYZ`'s properties to be visible (`[Bindable]`) in the Flex project in text controls.

Unfortunately, only `prop3` and `prop4` update when they are changed.  I've entered the debugger to make sure that `prop1` and `prop2` change, but they are not being updated in the text controls.

Here's the code:

### ABC.as

```
[Bindable]
public class ABC extends UIComponent {
    /* Other properties */

    public var xyz:XYZ = new XYZ();

    /* Methods that update xyz */
}
```

### XYZ.as

```
[Bindable]
public class XYZ extends Object {
     private var _prop1:uint = 0;
     private var _prop2:uint = 0;
     private var _prop3:uint = 0;
     private var _prop4:uint = 1;

     public function get prop1():uint {
         return _prop1;
     }

     public function set prop1(value:uint):void {
         _prop1 = value;
     }

     /* getters and setters for prop2, prop3, and prop4 */
}
```

### main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:com="com.*" />
    <com:ABC id="abc" />
    <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop1}" />
    <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop2}" />
    <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop3}" />
    <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop4}" />
</mx:Application>
```

## Answer

It's not apparent from the small code snippets that I posted, but from within `XYZ` I was updating `_prop3` and `_prop4` using their setters.  In constrast, I updated `_prop1` and `_prop2` through their private variables, not their setters.  Thus, properties 1 and 2 were not dispatching update events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your getters are returning voids.  They should be returning uints, according to your field types.

Otherwise your code should be working fine.  I've assembled and tested a working version with a Timer that sets all four values, so you can see all four updating:

**Main.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                var t:Timer = new Timer(1000);
                t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, t_tick);
                t.start();
            }

            private function t_tick(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                var i:uint = Timer(event.currentTarget).currentCount;

                abc.xyz.prop1 = i;
                abc.xyz.prop2 = i;
                abc.xyz.prop3 = i;
                abc.xyz.prop4 = i;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <local:ABC id="abc" />

    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop1}" />
        <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop2}" />
        <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop3}" />
        <mx:Text text="{abc.xyz.prop4}" />
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

**ABC.as**

```
package
{
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    [Bindable]
    public class ABC extends UIComponent
    {
        public var xyz:XYZ = new XYZ();

        public function ABC()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

**XYZ.as**

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class XYZ extends Object
    {
        private var _prop1:uint = 0;
        private var _prop2:uint = 0;
        private var _prop3:uint = 0;
        private var _prop4:uint = 1;

        public function XYZ()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function get prop1():uint {
            return _prop1;
        }

        public function set prop1(value:uint):void {
            _prop1 = value;
        }

        public function get prop2():uint {
            return _prop2;
        }

        public function set prop2(value:uint):void {
            _prop2 = value;
        }

        public function get prop3():uint {
            return _prop3;
        }

        public function set prop3(value:uint):void {
            _prop3 = value;
        }

        public function get prop4():uint {
            return _prop4;
        }

        public function set prop4(value:uint):void {
            _prop4 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at those, plug things in and you should see it all come together.  Post back if you have any questions.  Cheers.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I only made the void return type mistake here.  All of the setters in my actual code return uint.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok. Then the code I've posted here ought to work for you -- I've tested it to be sure. Feel free to give it a run and compare it to what you've got now, and use whichever pieces you need to fix things on your end. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry it's been so long but I've been away from the code for a little bit.  I just tried your test example and it worked, so I guess I have a bug elsewhere in my code.  Thanks!

Comment: Aha I fixed it.  It turns out when I changed properties 3 and 4 (from within XYZ) I was using the properties' setters, thus triggering the proper events to be dispatched.  With properties 1 and 2, I was changing them by modifying _prop1 and _prop2.  Since I wasn't calling the setters, no events were dispatched.  I guess I learned something today :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define your bindable sources through the use of getters and setters, the bindings don't seem to work. The solution is to declare a bindable event for your getter and dispatch the event in your setter:

```
[Bindable]
public class XYZ extends Object {
     private var _prop1:uint = 0;
     private var _prop2:uint = 0;
     private var _prop3:uint = 0;
     private var _prop4:uint = 1;

     [Bindable(event="prop1Changed")]
     public function get prop1():uint {
         return _prop1;
     }

     public function set prop1(value:uint):void {
         _prop1 = value;
         dispatchEvent (new Event ("prop1Changed"));
     }

     /* getters and setters for prop2, prop3, and prop4 */
}
```

So whenever your private member changes, an event is dispatched that notifies any component linked to the getter that the property has changed.

Comment: This isn't necessary if the class is marked [Bindable].  Also requires specific listeners be set up for each property -- it's fine as an illustration, but what the OP's asked is out-of-the-box stuff that should "just work" without all the extra goo.

Comment: You are right. If the class is marked as bindable there is no need to explicitly mark the properties also.